# C++ Overwriting Contents of a Handle

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I am trying to get a number from a HANDLE file, store it in an int, and possibly replace it in the same file.  My code right now looks like this

```cpp
HANDLE numFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  //Just in case file not found
numFile = CreateFile("numFile.txt", 
                     GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                     FILE_SHARE_READ, 
                     NULL, 
                     OPEN_EXISTING, 
                     FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                     NULL);
ReadFile(numFile, input, sizeof(char), &bytesRead, NULL);
int myNumber = input[0];
```

I know that there exists a WriteFile method in the API, but it looks like it will append the file as opposed to overwriting the contents.  I have briefly considered deleting and recreating the file each time, but this seems unnecessarily complex for this problem.  Any ideas out there?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea)?  You're using `OPEN_EXISTING` for the `dwCreationDisposition` parameter, when it sounds like you want `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`

Comment: Does this have to use the Windows API? There's standard file I/O that works across systems.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [SetFilePointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer) prior `WriteFile` for moving back to the begin

```
SetFilePointer(numFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this append the new number to the beginning of the file?  Instead of overwriting?

Comment: Append is possible only to the end of a file, any write in another position overwrites data at this position.

Comment: not need use `SetFilePointer`. need pass file offset in `OVERLAPPED`